# Разные значения слова "предавать"

Tags: однокоренные-слова

С одной стороны, "предавать" - это изменять кому-то или чему-то, то есть, становиться предателем. С другой, можно предавать, например, огню, то есть, не кого-то, а уже чему-то.
Второй случай мне понятен, а вот как быть с первым? Почему измена называется предательством? Кому или чему предается, так сказать, пострадавший?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ПРЕДАТЬ.
Из ст.-сл. яз., образовано от дати — «дать». Буквально значит ***«передать»***.(Этимологический словарь Русского языка. А.Ситникова . 2005).

Предатель ***передаёт*** себя кому-то другому. Измену называют предательством, так как изменивший оставляет доверявших ему, считавших его своим людей и передаёт себя и всё, чем он владеет, что он знает, тому, к кому он перешёл тайно или явно.

Answer (score 2):

Ну, ясно, врагу предается. То же самое.